# How to Display Multiple Series on a Single X-Axis in Kendo UI Chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, kendo-ui

I'm working with the Kendo UI library that visualizes project data using a chart. I have numbers series of data, seriesA and seriesB, which represent certain project metrics. My goal is to display both series on a single X-axis in a Kendo UI chart, with each series having its own color representation.

**My current code structure**

```
const ProjectContent: React.FC<{
    data: IProjectProjectData[];
}> = ({ data }) => {
    const seriesA = [19, 14];
    const seriesB = [25, 21];

    const onRender = (args: RenderEvent) => {
        const chart = args.target.chartInstance;
        if (!chart) {
            return;
        }
    };
    const underBudgetBandsA = [
        {
            from: 0,
            to: seriesA[0],
            color: "#e62325",
            opacity: 0.5,
            label: {
                text: seriesA[0].toFixed(),
                font: "12px sans-serif",
                color: "#444",
                margin: 5,
            },
        },
        {
            from: seriesA[0],
            to: seriesA[1],
            color: "#ffc000",
            opacity: 0.7,
            label: {
                text: seriesA[1].toFixed(),
                font: "12px sans-serif",
                color: "#444",
                margin: 5,
            },
        },
    ];

    const overBudgetBandsA = [
        {
            from: seriesA[1],
            to: seriesA[0] > seriesA[1] ? seriesA[0] : seriesA[1],
            color: "#60a82c",
            opacity: 0.5,
            label: {
                text:
                    seriesA[0] > seriesA[1]
                        ? seriesA[0].toFixed()
                        : seriesA[1].toFixed(),
                font: "12px sans-serif",
                color: "#444",
                margin: 5,
            },
        },
        {
            from: 0,
            to: seriesA[1],
            color: "#ffc000",
            opacity: 0.7,
            label: {
                text: seriesA[1].toFixed(),
                font: "12px sans-serif",
                color: "#444",
                margin: 5,
            },
        },
    ];

    const underBudgetBandsB = [
        {
            from: 0,
            to: seriesB[0],
            color: "#e62325",
            opacity: 0.5,
            label: {
                text: seriesB[0].toFixed(),
                font: "12px sans-serif",
                color: "#444",
                margin: 5,
            },
        },
        {
            from: seriesB[0],
            to: seriesB[1],
            color: "#c43545",
            opacity: 0.7,
            label: {
                text: seriesB[1].toFixed(),
                font: "12px sans-serif",
                color: "#444",
                margin: 5,
            },
        },
    ];

    const overBudgetBandsB = [
        {
            from: seriesB[1],
            to: seriesB[0] > seriesB[1] ? seriesB[0] : seriesB[1],
            color: "#e62325",
            opacity: 0.5,
            label: {
                text:
                    seriesB[0] > seriesB[1]
                        ? seriesB[0].toFixed()
                        : seriesB[1].toFixed(),
                font: "12px sans-serif",
                color: "#444",
                margin: 5,
            },
        },
        {
            from: 0,
            to: seriesB[1],
            color: "#c43545",
            opacity: 0.7,
            label: {
                text: seriesB[1].toFixed(),
                font: "12px sans-serif",
                color: "#444",
                margin: 5,
            },
        },
    ];

    return (
        <>
            <Chart onRender={onRender} style={{ height: 140 }}>
                <ChartLegend position="bottom" orientation="horizontal" />
                <ChartSeries>
                    <ChartSeriesItem
                        type="bullet"
                        color="#fff"
                        opacity={0}
                        data={seriesA}
                    />
                </ChartSeries>

                <ChartValueAxis>
                    <ChartValueAxisItem
                        min={0}
                        max={seriesA[0] > seriesA[1] ? seriesA[0] : seriesA[1]}
                        plotBands={
                            seriesA[0] < seriesA[1]
                                ? underBudgetBandsA
                                : overBudgetBandsA
                        }
                    />
                </ChartValueAxis>
            </Chart>
            <Chart onRender={onRender} style={{ height: 140 }}>
                <ChartLegend position="bottom" orientation="horizontal" />
                <ChartSeries>
                    <ChartSeriesItem
                        type="bullet"
                        color="#fff"
                        opacity={0}
                        data={seriesA}
                    />
                </ChartSeries>

                <ChartValueAxis>
                    <ChartValueAxisItem
                        min={0}
                        max={seriesB[0] > seriesB[1] ? seriesB[0] : seriesB[1]}
                        plotBands={
                            seriesB[0] < seriesB[1]
                                ? underBudgetBandsB
                                : overBudgetBandsB
                        }
                    />
                </ChartValueAxis>
            </Chart>
        </>
    );
};
```

my result
[image]

I want this
[image]

I'm encountering issues when trying to display both series on a single X-axis, and currently, the chart for seriesB is covering the chart for seriesA.

Any guidance or code examples on how to properly configure this chart to display both series with their own colors on a single X-axis would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!